# WPF Image source is being overriden

Tags: c#, wpf, image, user-controls, resources

I have a simple UserControl which only contains one image, which source is always Resource/imagename.jpg
Image properties are set to: `Build Action` Content, and `Copy to output directory` Copy always. This approach works on all regular windows, but when using it on UserControl, the Image itself is present, but it's source is always null (empty).

Here is the example of my UserControl

```
<UserControl x:Class="TSApp.UCPage2"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TSApp">
<Image x:Name="contentImage" Source="Resources/fb2.jpg"></Image></UserControl>
```

Here is the main window where UserControl is used:

```
<Grid x:Name="BookGrid">
    <local:Book x:Name="myBook" Width="1720" Height="640" Margin="25,0,25,1200">
        <local:Book.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#ECE2D0" Background="#BCA98A">
                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding .}" />
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </local:Book.ItemTemplate>
        <local:UCPage1 />
        <local:UCPage2 />
        <local:UCPage3 />
        <local:UCPage4 />
        <local:UCPage5 />
        <local:UCPage6 />
        <local:UCPage7 />
        <local:UCPage8 />
        <local:UCPage9 />
        <local:UCPage10 />
        <local:UCPage11 />
        <local:UCPage12 />
        <local:UCPage13 />
        <local:UCPage14 />
        <local:UCPage15 />
        <local:UCPage16 />
        <local:UCPage17 />
    </local:Book></Grid>
```

As you can expect, every page is loaded but Image source on every single page is empty. Is this somehow related to using UserControls instead of regular windows?

Also just to point out, there is no code behind that is interfering with these UserControls in any way.

Comment: The Build Action should of course be Resource, to make the file an assembly resource, i.e. compiled into the output assembly file. Besides that, it is entirely unclear why there is such a UserControl at all, insted of directly using an Image element.

Comment: That was my first approach, but that however does not fix my problem, which is the source of the image.

Comment: Try an explicit full Resource File Pack URI like `Source="pack://application:,,,/TSApp;component/Resources/fb2.jpg"` where TSApp might be replaced by the name of the UserControl's assembly.

Comment: This indeed solves the problem. Do you mind posting a solution where you can explain why this is the case? I'm still confused how comes on normal windows I can just use Source="Resources/fb2.jpg", but not on UserControls?